# How to convert 3d model to solid color in unity?

Tags: unity-game-engine, game-engine, game-physics, rigid-bodies, collider

I have a city 3d model as a folder. The folder includes .obj file, materials and textures.

I try to create a virtual tour by walking on the roads. I place my camera on a street.My camera goes forward and back by clicking up and down keys. It rotates trun and left by clicking right and left keys. I can handle key press successfully.

The city model has a different height from ground. It looks like below image : 
[image]

If the user press up or down key, I change only z value by update transfrom.Translate data :

```
float translation = Input.GetAxis("Vertical") * speed;
transform.Translate(0, 0, translation);
```

But my camera goes under black line, and I cannot see the city properly. How can I avoid to go under the line(roads) ? Do making solid object solve my problem?

Answer (score 1):

There are a few approaches you could take. I would suggest adding a [mesh collider](http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-MeshCollider.html) to your road, and then doing a [raycast](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Physics.Raycast.html) from your object's position, down towards it. It would look something like:

```
RaycastHit hit;
float height = 1.0f;
if(Physics.Raycast(transform.positon, -Vector3.up, out hit))
{
    transform.position = Vector3(transform.position.x, hit.point.y + height, transform.position.z);
}
```

Comment: I think that meybe there is an automatic solution by using  rigidbody or other.

Comment: Just to add one thing. Unless the road has a really unusual mesh I would recommend going with a box collider. Addig a rigidbody and collider to the camera should work too, just make sure that the physics material is frictionless so that the cam does not slow down on collisions.

Comment: Yes, you could also do this using a rigid body, but because you aren't moving the gameobject via forces in the physics system (you are directly setting it's position) it's generally not a good idea.

Comment: @M.Palko I tried your solution. It works nicely on the road. if the player goes towards to buildings, the camera goes under the city. How can I prevent to go through buildings?